# Error when installing TFS 2012 Update 1 - dbo.typ_BuildControllerTableV2 is incompatible with dbo.typ_BuildControllerTable

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

I've just downloaded and installed Team Foundation Server 2012 Update 1 on my TFS2012 server and now I can't configure a build controller or edit build definitions.

I downloaded the update from here:
Team Foundation Server 2012 with Update 1 ([web installer](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810334) or 1.1 GB [ISO file](http://go.microsoft.com/?linkid=9810324))

Then I ran the installer on my server that contains both the Application Tier and Data Tier on the same box.

Then I ran the installer on my other server that is a Build Controller and Build Agent. It required me to reconfigure the build controller, but the wizard failed with the following error:

[image: Build Service Configuration Wizard - Unable to register with TFS]

When I look in the event log of the application tier, I see the following error:

```
Detailed Message: TF30065: An unhandled exception occurred.

Web Request Details
    Url: http://tfs.contoso.com:8080/tfs/Collection/Build/v4.0/AdministrationService.asmx [method: POST]
    User Agent: Team Foundation (TfsMgmt.exe, 11.0.51106.1, Other, SKU:9)
    Headers: Content-Length=405&Content-Type=application%2fsoap%2bxml%3b+charset%3dutf-8&Accept-Encoding=gzip&Accept-Language=en-AU&Expect=100-continue&Host=tfs.contoso.com%3a8080&User-Agent=Team+Foundation+(TfsMgmt.exe%2c+11.0.51106.1%2c+Other%2c+SKU%3a9)&X-TFS-Version=1.0.0.0&X-TFS-Session=21fd1d52-8afa-455c-bcc8-32ee83fa39a2%2c+AddBuildControllers&SOAPAction=%22http%3a%2f%2fschemas.microsoft.com%2fTeamFoundation%2f2010%2fBuild%2fAddBuildControllers%22
    Path: /tfs/Collection/Build/v4.0/AdministrationService.asmx
    Local Request: False
    Host Address: 192.168.1.100
    User: DOMAIN\TFSBUILDSVC [authentication type: NTLM]

Exception Message: TF30040: The database is not correctly configured. Contact your Team Foundation Server administrator. (type DatabaseConfigurationException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(Int32 errorNumber, SqlException sqlException, SqlError sqlError)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.TranslateException(SqlException sqlException)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.MapException(SqlException ex, QueryExecutionState queryState)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.HandleException(Exception exception)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.DataAccess.AdministrationComponent.AddBuildControllers(IList`1 controllers)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.TeamFoundationBuildResourceService.AddBuildControllers(TeamFoundationRequestContext requestContext, IList`1 controllers)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Build.Server.AdministrationWebService4.AddBuildControllers(List`1 controllers)

Inner Exception Details:

Exception Message: Operand type clash: dbo.typ_BuildControllerTableV2 is incompatible with dbo.typ_BuildControllerTable (type SqlException)
SQL Exception Class: 16
SQL Exception Number: 206
SQL Exception Procedure: 
SQL Exception Line Number: 1
SQL Exception Server: tfsdata.contoso.com
SQL Exception State: 3
SQL Error(s):

Exception Data Dictionary:
HelpLink.ProdName = Microsoft SQL Server
HelpLink.ProdVer = 11.00.2100
HelpLink.EvtSrc = MSSQLServer
HelpLink.EvtID = 206
HelpLink.BaseHelpUrl = http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink
HelpLink.LinkId = 20476


Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection.OnError(SqlException exception, Boolean breakConnection, Action`1 wrapCloseInAction)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.ThrowExceptionAndWarning(TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean callerHasConnectionLock, Boolean asyncClose)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.TdsParser.TryRun(RunBehavior runBehavior, SqlCommand cmdHandler, SqlDataReader dataStream, BulkCopySimpleResultSet bulkCopyHandler, TdsParserStateObject stateObj, Boolean& dataReady)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.TryConsumeMetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader.get_MetaData()
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.FinishExecuteReader(SqlDataReader ds, RunBehavior runBehavior, String resetOptionsString)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReaderTds(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, Boolean async, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method, TaskCompletionSource`1 completion, Int32 timeout, Task& task, Boolean asyncWrite)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.RunExecuteReader(CommandBehavior cmdBehavior, RunBehavior runBehavior, Boolean returnStream, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior, String method)
   at System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior behavior)
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Framework.Server.TeamFoundationSqlResourceComponent.Execute(ExecuteType executeType, CommandBehavior behavior)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
TF30040: The database is not correctly configured.
```

First of all, this error message is an indication of a schema/version mismatch between the binaries installed on the server and the database schema.

The bad news is that this is a caching bug where the server.

**Workaround**

The good news is that it can be easily worked around by running the following commands on your Application Tier server. After this, you should be able to configure your build servers.

```
iisreset
net stop tfsjobagent
net start tfsjobagent
```

With TFS 2012 Update 2 and later versions, this issue has been fixed.